# Stationary/Inflection Point(s) when $\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{-2x}(1-2x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When $\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{-2x}(1-2x)$, stationary point will be when $x=\frac{1}{2}$? How come in my book, theres an inflection point when $x=1$? I thought inflection point is also a stationary point? So it should be gotten by setting $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$, which got me only $x=\frac{1}{2}$?

[image]

Comment: Inflection points occur when $f''$ changes sign ($f$ switches concavity). So, candidates for inflection points are found by solving $f''(x)=0)$. (Or f''(x)$ does not exist.)

Comment: You thought that inflection point means stationary point. That is not correct! Inflection is where y'' = 0

Comment: [classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_point#Classification)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stationary points are where $f'(x)=0$. So for your example, $x=1/2$ is the stationary point.

Inflection points occur when the graph of $f$ switches concavity. This occurs when $f''$ changes sign. Candidates for inflection points are found by finding points where $f''(x)=0$ or not exist.

The tangent line at an inflection point need not have 0 slope. Look at $y=\tan x$ at $x=0$, or your example.

Comment: I should point out that inflection points occur at points $x=c$ where $f'$ has a local extreme value. So, the candidates for inflection points of $f$ are the stationary points of $f'$ (these are the points where $(f')'=f''$ is zero) or points where $(f')'=f''$ does not exist.